# Python-Sqlalchemy-Postgres : How to store subquery result in a variable and use it to a master query

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, query-optimization, python-3.6

I Have a subquery which being used in multiple where conditions in my main query. Due to this the subquery executes multiple times to get the same result. is there a way to store and use the subquery result so that it would execute only once.

Sample code:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.schema import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Text
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import select, union

Base = declarative_base()
class Table1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table1'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    uuid = Column(Text, unique=True, nullable=False)
    
class Table2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table2'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    uuid = Column(Text, unique=True, nullable=False)
    
class Table3(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table3'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    uuid = Column(Text, unique=True, nullable=False)
    

class Table4(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table4'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(Text, nullable=False)


class Table5(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table5'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    res_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('table4.id'), nullable=False)
    value = Column(Text, nullable=False)

class Table1Map(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table1_map'

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('table4.id'), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    map_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('table1.id'), primary_key=True, unique=True, nullable=False)

class Table2Map(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table2_map'

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('table4.id'), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    map_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('table2.id'), primary_key=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    
class Table3Map(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table3_map'

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('table4.id'), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    map_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('table3.id'), primary_key=True, unique=True, nullable=False)


sub_query = select([Table5.__table__.c.id]).where(Table5.__table__.c.value=='somevalue')
subquery_1 = select([Table1.__table__.c.uuid.label("map_id"), Table1Map.__table__.c.id.label("id")]).select_from(Table1.__table__.join(Table1Map.__table__, Table1Map.__table__.c.map_id==Table1.__table__.c.id)).where(Table1Map.__table__.c.id.in_(sub_query))

subquery_2 = select([Table2.__table__.c.uuid.label("map_id"), Table2Map.__table__.c.id.label("id")]).select_from(Table2.__table__.join(Table2Map.__table__, Table2Map.__table__.c.map_id==Table2.__table__.c.id)).where(Table2Map.__table__.c.id.in_(sub_query))

subquery_3 = select([Table3.__table__.c.uuid.label("map_id"), Table3Map.__table__.c.id.label("id")]).select_from(Table3.__table__.join(Table3Map.__table__, Table3Map.__table__.c.map_id==Table3.__table__.c.id)).where(Table3Map.__table__.c.id.in_(sub_query))

main_query = union(subquery_1, subquery_2, subquery_3)

print(main_query)
```

This Produces the below query. I need to avoid this subquery being repeatedly executed multiple times.

```
SELECT TABLE1.UUID AS MAP_ID,
    TABLE1_MAP.ID AS ID
FROM TABLE1
JOIN TABLE1_MAP ON TABLE1_MAP.MAP_ID = TABLE1.ID
WHERE TABLE1_MAP.ID IN
        (SELECT TABLE5.ID
            FROM TABLE5
            WHERE TABLE5.VALUE = 'some_value')
UNION
SELECT TABLE2.UUID AS MAP_ID,
    TABLE2_MAP.ID AS ID
FROM TABLE2
JOIN TABLE2_MAP ON TABLE2_MAP.MAP_ID = TABLE2.ID
WHERE TABLE2_MAP.ID IN
        (SELECT TABLE5.ID
            FROM TABLE5
            WHERE TABLE5.VALUE = 'some_value')
UNION
SELECT TABLE3.UUID AS MAP_ID,
    TABLE3_MAP.ID AS ID
FROM TABLE3
JOIN TABLE3_MAP ON TABLE3_MAP.MAP_ID = TABLE3.ID
WHERE TABLE3_MAP.ID IN
        (SELECT TABLE5.ID
            FROM TABLE5
            WHERE TABLE5.VALUE = 'some_value')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why?  Have you run `explain (analyze, buffers)` sufficiently to show it is actually causing performance issues. It is quite possible the repeated executions finds the necessary value already in memory so does not require additional IO.  However, the way to accomplish this in Postgres would be selecting the value from table5 in a CTE:  (sorry I do not know your obfuscation manager, Python-Sqlalchemy).

```
with cte (id) as 
     (select id 
        from table5 t5
       where t5.value = 'some_value'
     )          
select t1.uuid as map_id 
       t1m.id as id
  from table1 t1
  join table1_map on t1m.id = t1.id
  where t1m.id in
        (select  id
            from cte
        )
select t2.uuid as map_id 
       t2m.id as id
  from table2 t2
  join table2_map on t2m.id = t2.id
  where t2m.id in
        (select  id
            from cte
        )  
select t3.uuid as map_id 
       t3m.id as id
  from table3 t3
  join table3_map on t3m.id = t3.id
  where t3m.id in
        (select  id
            from cte
        );
```

Notice that you still have the repeat the sub-select (just referencing the CTE). If you insist on removing any repetition you can of course perform the union in a sub-select then filter the ids.

```
select uuid, id
  from (select t1.uuid 
              , t1.id    
           from table1 t1 
        union 
        select t2.uuid 
             , t2.id    
          from table2 t2
        union
        select t3.uuid 
             , t3.id    
          from table3 t3 
       )  tall 
where tall.id in 
      (select t5.id
         from table5 t5
        where t5.value = 'some_value'
      );
```

Either way run explain to see what actually performs the best in your environment. (Make sure it has production volume. IE do no run tests on tables with 100s of rows if your production has 100K rows).  

**NOT TESTED.**  

*NOTE:* It is a bad idea having a column name `uuid`. Postgres support the native data type `uuid`. Poor choice of names leads to confusion (developers not Postgres) and confusion leads to bugs. Often undetected until is becomes a critical production problem.

Comment: Thanks @Belayer. The CTE Helps, Yes, I have run explain analyze and the plan executes the subquery every time. with the CTE that is solved. 
Also I am testing with 12Million rows in table5 and all other tables have 1Million rows. I have the indexes for all these tables.

Comment: Lets take this one select

`select t3.uuid as map_id  t3m.id as id from table3 t3 join table3_map on t3m.id = t3.id where t3m.id in (select  id from cte); `
I have the indexes for `t3m.id` and `t3.id`. 
in the plan the `in` operation between `t3m.id = t3.id` (index scan)  and CTE scan is not so fast. Yeah it is comparatively very fast than executing the subquery every time. But the Nested loop operation between CTE scan and Index scan is slower than the index scan to index scan. is there anything that we can do to further optimize this query?